# IdentityServer4 works only with HTTPS

Tags: identityserver4

I'm migrating from Identity Server 3 to 4.
I'm having trouble running Identity Server 4 without HTTPS in local development environment.
With HTTPS - everything works fine. Without it the user is not authenticated and just redirected
to the login page. The cookie is not set.

I know Identity Server 3 used to have the RequireSsl option that is now gone.
I've searched the docs for hours but came with nothing.

I'm on IdentityServer4 4.1.1 and AspNet Core 3.1
My Startup.cs looks like this:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Configs.Resources.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Configs.Resources.GetApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Configs.Resources.GetApiScopes())
                .AddTestUsers(Users.Get())
                ..AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, you try it in Chrome. When you open dev console (F12) most likely you find the warnings that `SameSite=None` cookie must be secure.

If my above guess is right, there could two possible causes: you use customized `CookieAuthenticationOptions` where you explicitly set `options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None` (looking at your startup you don't), or the [default one](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/3d3b6dcfef2eea1e375a6ec867ae947cede094d2/src/IdentityServer4/src/Configuration/DependencyInjection/ConfigureInternalCookieOptions.cs#L33) is not good for your configuration.

You can tweak it like below:

```cs
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.Authentication.CookieSameSiteMode = SameSiteMode.Lax;
})
```

Will work on localhost, will block silent refresh for clients hosted beyond your IdSrv's root domain. So you have to choose whether you prefer Lax for production, or just for home playground (but in general None it not recommended anywhere).

Comment: You're right. I'm trying it in Chrome. Tried it in MS Edge now and there it works. Unfortunately the CookieAuthenticationOptions don't fix it for Chrome.

Comment: My mistake. It works! Must have not rebuilt it or something.. Too much tweaking today. Thank you very much for your help. I see I must read about the whole same site thing. :)

Comment: I suggest to use https locally and avoid changing the samesite, this will break some cases of OIDC such as iframe  - you can use asp.net core development certificates locally for https and its very easy to setup https://nahidfa.com/posts/asp-.net-core-https-development-certificate-on-windows/

Comment: @nahidf, I mentioned that in the answer. Anyway the general approach should be to avoid using None where possible, as the plans of Google is to deprecate it at all. For sure that must be the informed decision. For now None just works in most situations, but the things change rapidly and it's good to be prepared.